# Using regex to find certain range

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex to find a range between 1-31. This is what i have so far but its not working. Also could someone please explain to me how the regex formatting works?

```
1[0-3]?|2[0-9]|[1-9]
```

Comment: Why not just convert to a integer first and check its value?

Comment: Because i have to code defensively against letters be entered and i dont know how to use try and catch

Comment: @user3421292 try/catch is much easier than regex

Comment: What does it mean to "find a range"?  When you say "not working", what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened?  A regexp either (a) finds a substring in a larger string that matches a pattern, or (b) checks that a given string matches the pattern.  Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the 1-9, 10-29 and 30-31 cases separately like this.

```
[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]
```

Comment: Would "01" be in that range?

Comment: @Malvolio No.  I've assumed leading zeroes are illegal.

Comment: Ahh, so your question is, "How can I use regex to determine if the string represents, without leading zeros or decimal point, an integer between 1 and 31?"  Are you sure you want regex to do that?  You are killing a fly with a sledge-hammer.

Comment: @Malvolio It's way easier than using `parseInt` and catching the exception.

Comment: I think you and I have a very different notion of what constitutes "easier", but since you have to live with it, it is your call.

Comment: @Malvolio feel free to post an answer that uses `Integer.parseInt` along with `try / catch(NumberFormatException ...` then checks whether the value is between 1 and 31.  I might even upvote it; but I'm unlikely to prefer it over simply writing `myString.matches("[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]")`

Comment: One more question, what if i wanted to do the same thing but instead of 1-31 i wanted 1-59

Comment: @DavidWallace `myString.matches("0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])")` for leading zeros?

Comment: @user342192 Are you validating dates and times?  If so, don't re-invent the wheel.  Check out `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I looked into SimpleDateFormat but i was having trouble implementing it, and someone suggested that i do this

Comment: Nope.  Don't do this.  Seriously, use `SimpleDateFormat` if you are parsing dates and times.  If you're having trouble with it, post another question.

Comment: You may be able to put together your several regexes to match your various date and time component ranges, but you can't simply match to check the overall combination is valid... e.g. Feb 31 as 2/31/2014 can match, but isn't valid.  Seriously, learn to use the DateFormat `.parse(String)` method.

Comment: Someone *foolish* suggested you do this!  DateFormat is a fairly complicated area, but extremely well-covered by libraries.  Reinventing a wheel usually results in a crappy wheel!

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

Here's the verbose version, which also throws up two other useful functions:

```
... {
   static public int asInt(String s, int dflt) {
        try {
          return parseInt(s, 10);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          return dflt;
        }
   }

   static public boolean isInRange(int n, int mn, int mx) {
       return (n >= mn) && (n <= mx);
   }

   static public boolean isBetween1and31(String s) {
       return isInRange(asInt(s, 0), 1, 31);
   }
}
```

Comment: OK, you have my upvote, even though your answer isn't really to my taste.

Comment: *De gustibus non est disputandum*, but I would ask you to consider the following things when comparing the two approaches: 1. If it didn't work, how would you debug it? 2. What other purposes might the code be put to? 3. If the requirement were to change slightly (e.g, upper bounds of 32, read bounds from a file), how would the code change? 4. Could someone unfamiliar with the code review it readily? 5. How long would it take to execute?

Answer (score 0):

```
([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

This would be enough to generate a regex b/w a range.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer I posted 43 months ago?

Comment: Yeah its same... but just look at the rest of the two lines